# LDAP restricting the limit of size

Tags: ldap-query

I need to filter the AD description field, such that LDAP should exclude all the records which description length is more than 500 characters.

Could somebody help me to in this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way with LDAP to set a filter on the length of values, as there is no standard LDAP matching rule for this.